# ng new does fail to untar cache

Tags: angularjs, npm, angular-cli, typescript-typings

I try to create a new Angular2 Application using angular-cli, but can not get it to work properly.

ng new fails during the npm step: `Installing packages for tooling via npm`

```
Installing packages for tooling via npm
typings ERR! message Unable to connect to "https://api.typings.org/entries/dt/es6-shim/tags/0.31.2%2B20160317120654"
typings ERR! caused by getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND company company:443

typings ERR! cwd D:\Source\testsdfsa
typings ERR! system Windows_NT 6.3.9600
typings ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Source\\testsdfsa\\node_modules\\typings\\dist\\bin.js" "install"
typings ERR! node -v v4.4.7
typings ERR! typings -v 0.8.1
typings ERR! code EUNAVAILABLE
```

if i try to run npm install afterwards i get the same error. Rebooting, starting from scratch and clearing cache did not change anything.

If i try to install again after the first fail without clearing the cache i get the following errors:

```
untar error C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-2280-3cd29f2f\
               registry.npmjs.org\source-map\-\source-map-0.5.6.tgz

untar error C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-2280-3cd29f2f\
               registry.npmjs.org\source-map\-\source-map-0.5.6.tgz

untar error C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-2280-3cd29f2f\
               registry.npmjs.org\bluebird\-\bluebird-3.4.1.tgz
unexpected eof
Error: unexpected eof
at decorate (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:67:36)
at Extract.Abstract.error (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\abstract.js:61:12)
at Extract._streamEnd (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\extract.js:91:35)
at BlockStream.<anonymous> (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:51:8)
at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
at BlockStream.emit (events.js:166:7)
at BlockStream._emitChunk (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:203:10)
at BlockStream.flush (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:70:8)
at BlockStream.end (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\node_modules\block-stream\block-stream.js:66:8)
at Extract.Parse.end (C:\Users\schnaitlr\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\angular-cli\node_modules\npm\node_modules\tar\lib\parse.js:86:23)
```

Comment: Can you try `npm install typings` and let me know if there is a problem or not. And are you using a local proxy? Please check that it's configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was causing the problem:
I configured our proxy in the .typingsrc file using

```
HTTP://DOMAIN\user:pass@url:port
```

but typings like npm does replace the backward slash with a forward one. which makes our proxy fail the authentication. Encoding the backslash fixes the issue

```
HTTP://DOMAIN%5Cuser:pass@url:port
```

Comment: That is what I was asking in your question :)